# JPA/Hibernate querying but not assigning sub-object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

OK, I think there is some missing in my understanding of JPA/Hibernate. I have two tables: STUDENTS that represents a student, and CC that represents a student's assignment to a class. The CC table has a STUDENTID column that refers to the student. I am trying to do a simple query where I return CC records with their associated student records. My CC class looks like this (lots of stuff deleted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cc")
public class CC {
    ...
    @Column(name="studentid", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer studentid;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="studentid", referencedColumnName="id",
        insertable=false, updatable=false) })
    private Student student;
    ...
}
```

I have to specify referencedColumnName because "ID" is not the primary key of the STUDENTS table. I am trying to query as follows:

```
EntityManager em = getCurrentEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery ( "select cc from CC cc inner join fetch cc.student where cc.sectionid=:sectionid");
query.setParameter("sectionid", sectionId);
List<CC> rows = query.getResultList();
if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(rows)) for (CC cc: rows) {
    Student student = cc.getStudent();
    //// PROBLEM: student object is null here (though studentid is correct)!
}
```

I can see hibernate is doing the query correctly, joining the tables together and even returning the columns of the student table in the query projection:

```
select cc0_.dcid as dcid21_0_, student1_.DCID as DCID7_1_, cc0_.course_number as course2_21_0_,
... student1_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST28_7_1_, student1_.GENDER as GENDER7_1_, ...
from cc cc0_ inner join STUDENTS student1_ 
on cc0_.studentid=student1_.ID where cc0_.sectionid=?
```

The problem, as noted above, is that the "student" sub-object of CC is always null, even though the STUDENTID column is not null and is correct. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: wouldn't be better for you to iteract a list of students and get their CCs?

Comment: If I was looking for all the classes a given student is in, then yes. But I'm looking for the opposite information: I want all the CC records for a given class, and I need the student's information at the same time.

Comment: why you need studentid column  private Student student;
 column already stored in db as a foreign key  refering to student.

Comment: I may be mistaken here, but here's my thinking: This class CC is an existing class. Most callers will not be getting the Student object with the CC, however many of them do use the studentId column that's already in CC. My thinking was that if I made getStudentId() instead return student.id, those callers' queries would be modified. I don't *think* I want that, because it means regression risk.

Comment: I suspect that you have a table called class which has a many to many relationship to student. In this scenario CC would be a join table and shouldn't have a class unless the table supplies more than that. You can then call getStudents() on a Class object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be mistaken about the way hibernate does fetching, however, this line right here may prove your sticking point:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
```

Since you're telling Hibernate to use `LAZY` fetching, it's not pulling back the persisted `Student` objects for the `Class` object referenced.  This helps with query load time, Hibernate optimizes out objects sub-class inheritance with lazy loading turned on.  If you change the fetch type to `EAGER` I think you'll see the results you're expecting.